Combinations and forming groups
In how many ways can three groups of 3 be made from letters of the word CROCODILE? PS: Answer is 140 but I fail to see the logic. My take was (9C3 *6C3 *3C3) / (3! *2! *2!) =70 but its wrong

This is phrased poorly.  What's a "group" in this context?  Do you mean an ordered sequence?  Do you mean an unordered set?  That is, are $COD$ and $DCO$ the same "group" or not?  Are the groups labeled?  That is, does permuting the selection of the three groups produce a new solution?

If you think of the problem as calling for unordered, unlabeled collections (as I think you are), then it's a bit tricky to handle collections like $CCR$.  "switching" the two $C's$ does not change that collection.  Of course, it would change the ordered version, as $C_1C_2R$ is not the same as $C_2C_1R$.


I take it that the groups are unlabeled, as you have also done.
On computing, I am getting an answer in between your answer and the book's
The strategy I have used is to first place the two "twins" and then place the balance.
In some cases, division by $2$ is due to symmetrical placing of "twins" in two boxes

$CCO\mid O \; or\; OOC\mid C \implies 2\cdot\binom52 = 20$
$CC\mid OO \implies \binom51\binom41 = 20$
$CO \mid CO \implies \binom51\binom41\color{red}{\div 2} = 10$
$CC\mid O\mid O\; or\; OO\mid C\mid C \implies 2\cdot\binom51\binom42 \color{red}{\div 2} = 30$
$CO\mid C\mid O \implies \binom51\binom42 = 30$
Adding up gives an answer of $\;\boxed{110}$

As lulu commented,  treating the problem as unordered, unlabeled collections is tricky !

Thank you so much...actually,110 is the answer I am seeking...sorry for poor phrasing..Actually the query I have posted is part of a bigger question. I am posting same below. Could you tell me how you would proceed? Again, the marking scheme is giving the answer as 80 while I am having an answer of 65.

Find the number of ways in which the 9 letters in the word CROCODILE can be divided into
three groups, each containing three letters, if the two Cs must be in different groups.

All you beed to do is to add up the cases in the answer where the two C's are in different groups, thus proceeding case by written case, $20/2+ 0+ 10+30/2+30=65$ By the way, when any answer satisfies you, you are supposed to tick it as accepted
